# C# error from redeclaration of Pattern Matching variable in conditional

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The following code gives an error: "A local or parameter named 'ac' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter".

```
    if (action is ActionRegisterNewDevice ac)
    {
        state = state.ShallowCopy();
        // Initialise the device to off
        state.DeviceOn[ac.ObjectId] = false;
    }
    else if (action is ActionOnMouseDown ac)
    {
        state = state.ShallowCopy();
        // toggle the state of the device
        state.DeviceOn[ac.ObjectId] = !DeviceSelectors.Device_is_on(state, ac.ObjectId);
    }
```

I was under the impression (obviously incorrectly) that the first conditional is a separate scope.  It seems that the Pattern matching, even when false, still declares the variable `ac`.

However [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) says:

> Language rules for pattern matching expressions help you avoid
>   misusing the results of a match expression. In the example above, the
>   variables s, c, and r are only in scope and definitely assigned when
>   the respective pattern match expressions have true results. If you try
>   to use either variable in another location, your code generates
>   compiler errors.

This error can apparently only be fixed by renaming the second `ac` to something else.  Is this correct?  Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

[image]

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: @GaryStewart have clarified that I want clarification.  What am I misunderstanding about the documentation please.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your code to use a switch statement instead to get the behaviour you want:

```
void Main()
{
    Print("Hello world");
    Print(42);
}

static void Print(object o)
{
    switch (o)
    {
        // Note that I am reusing the variable name "value" in each case.
        case string value:
            Console.WriteLine("STRING: " + value);
            break;

        case int value:
            Console.WriteLine("INT: " + value.ToString());
            break;
    }
}
```

To answer your question of why you can't do this in an `if...else...`, this is called out in the documentation you link to:

> The variable s is in scope in the method ComputeAreaModernIs. That's because each branch of an if statement establishes a separate scope for variables. However, the if statement itself doesn't.

Comment: The example in the documentation shows it working with an `if-else if`.  I would like to understand why my code is not working as the documentation says it should... perhaps I have misinterpreted the documentation?

Comment: The example in the documentation does not show that though - they use 3 different variables: `Square s`, `Circle c`, and `Rectangle r`. Basically, it doesn't work because if statements don't create a new scope. I've updated my answer to answer the question you asked :)

Comment: Thanks @RB. I'm used to Type Guards in Typescript where you don't even need to assign a new variable: the variable you've typed in that scope has the new narrowed type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards  I've put in a switch statement and it works well.  Thanks again.